Adding bullet point to multiline TextField
I have a multiline OutlinedTextField. When the user adds a new line I want to programmatically also add a bullet point followed by a whitespace. So far I achieve this but the issue is after adding the bullet point the cursor position is still at the newline, not after bullet point.
This is my TextField composable:
@Composable
fun ExperienceDescTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    placeholder: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val colorsOfTextFields = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        cursorColor = Color.Black,
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
        focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
        unfocusedBorderColor = onPrimaryColor,
        focusedBorderColor = onPrimaryColor,
        focusedTextColor = onPrimaryColor,
        disabledTextColor = onPrimaryColor,
        unfocusedPlaceholderColor = onPrimaryLightColor,
        focusedPlaceholderColor = onPrimaryLightColor
    )
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { newValue ->
            val updatedValue = if (newValue.endsWith("\n")) {
                // Append bullet point and indentation if a new line is entered
                val bulletPoint = "\u25CF\t"
                newValue + bulletPoint
            } else if (newValue.endsWith("\u25CF")) {
                newValue.dropLast(2)
            } else {
                newValue
            }

            val fieldValue =
                TextFieldValue(text = updatedValue, selection = TextRange(updatedValue.length))
            Log.e("TAG", "ExperienceDescTextField: $fieldValue")
            onValueChange(fieldValue.text)
        },
        /*onValueChange = { newValue ->
            onValueChange(newValue)
        },*/
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            color = onPrimaryColor,
            fontFamily = poppinsFont,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,

            ),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text, imeAction = ImeAction.Default
        ),
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                placeholder,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                fontFamily = poppinsFont,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal
            )
        },
        colors = colorsOfTextFields,
        singleLine = false,
        minLines = 4,
        maxLines = 7
    )
}

And from my screen I am calling it as follows:
ExperienceDescTextField(
    value = viewModel.jobDescription.value,
    onValueChange = {
        viewModel.jobDescription.value = it
    },
    placeholder = stringResource(R.string.get_help_writing_your_bullet_points_with_help_of_ai_powered_examples_below),
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
)

